# How to exclude xml object using xslt with dependencies

Tags: xml, xslt

I've the following input xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <root> 
        <technicalAssets>
            <composedId>
                <id>A1</id> 
            </composedId> 
            <technicalName>TestA1</technicalName> 
            <prerequisites>
                <technicalAssetPrerequisites> 
                    <technicalAssetIds>
                        <composedId>
                            <id>B1</id> 
                        </composedId>
                    </technicalAssetIds>
                </technicalAssetPrerequisites> 
            </prerequisites>
        </technicalAssets>

        <technicalAssets>
            <composedId>
                <id>A2</id> 
            </composedId> 
            <technicalName>TestA2</technicalName> 
        </technicalAssets>

        <technicalAssets>
            <composedId>
                <id>B1</id> 
            </composedId> 
            <technicalName>TestB1</technicalName> 
        </technicalAssets>  

        <products> 
            <entitlementRules>       
                <technicalAssetId>
                    <composedId>
                        <id>A1</id> 
                    </composedId>
                </technicalAssetId>
            </entitlementRules> 

        </products> 

    </root>
```

I would like to apply an XSLT transformation that lists only the `technicalAssets` that are either referenced in the *products* or those which are referenced by them.

How can I achieve that?
Expected Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root> 
    <technicalAssets>
        <composedId>
            <id>A1</id> 
        </composedId> 
        <technicalName>TestA1</technicalName> 
        <prerequisites>
            <technicalAssetPrerequisites> 
                <technicalAssetIds>
                    <composedId>
                        <id>B1</id> 
                    </composedId>
                </technicalAssetIds>
            </technicalAssetPrerequisites> 
        </prerequisites>
    </technicalAssets>

    <technicalAssets>
        <composedId>
            <id>B1</id> 
        </composedId> 
        <technicalName>TestB1</technicalName> 
    </technicalAssets>  

    <products> 
        <entitlementRules>       
            <technicalAssetId>
                <composedId>
                    <id>A1</id> 
                </composedId>
            </technicalAssetId>
        </entitlementRules> 

    </products> 

</root>
```

I'm currently using the following xslt, but it copies the node technicalAssets inside product node where the technicalAssetId appears. That is not what I need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="technicalAssets"/>

    <xsl:template match="technicalAssetId">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/> 
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/technicalAssets[composedId/id/text() = current()/composedId/id/text()]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm expecting the following not to be part of the output

<technicalAssets>
  <composedId>
   <id>A2</id> 
  </composedId> 
  <technicalName>TestA2</technicalName> 
 </technicalAssets>

Comment: the list of <technicalAssets> is unbounded 1:n. The xslt need to be dynamically doing the check and copy.
same to the <entitlementRules>.

Comment: Please add the expected output and your current XSLT to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [`xsl:key`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-key) to select all `composedId/id`'s that aren't direct children of `technicalAssets`.

You can then use [`key()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#function-key) in a predicate in a template that matches `technicalAssets` to check to see if there isn't a key that matches `composedId/id`.

So instead of trying to copy what you want to keep, you remove what you don't want to keep.

Example...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="ids" match="*[not(self::technicalAssets)]/composedId/id" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="technicalAssets[not(key('ids',composedId/id))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Fiddle: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rewNya

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you so much. it works for few technicalAssets. the more not relevant technicalAssets I've in the xml, the more technicalAssets will be remaining. any thought?

Comment: @AndreasG. - Sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. Do you mind updating the input/output XML examples in your question that my suggestion doesn't handle correctly? I should be able to make an update to my answer once it's clear how it's not working correctly. Thanks!

Comment: can you check http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94AbWBc
as you will see there is under products/entitlementRules/technicalAssetId/composedId/id            
only one technicalassetId 6795ac78-6f09-456d-90ea-673662dae82c
but as result we have 10 'technicalAssets' that are not equal to the one above.

Comment: good morning experts, any thought about the above issue? @Daniel has provided a very good solution. although it does seem to ignore some 'technicalAssets'. very appropriated if someone could have a closer look.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it like this now:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
      <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
      <xsl:template match="technicalAssets[composedId/id != //entitlementRules/technicalAssetId/composedId/id]"/>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```